# Given an invertible complex $n\times n$ matrix $P$, does $PP^*$ commute with with all $n\times n$ with all complex matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, bilinear-form, hermitian-matrices

The answer is a simple No as: if
$P=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\\
1 & \\
\end{bmatrix}$
then $PP^*=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\\
& 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

and
$PP^* \begin{bmatrix} 
& 1\\
 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

and $ \begin{bmatrix} 
& 1\\
 \\
\end{bmatrix}
PP^*=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

But I seem to have a set of arguments which says the answer to the question is YES. Please help me find my mistake.

Fact 1: A complex vector space together with a positive definite hermitian form is hermitian

Fact 2: A change of basis to $\textbf{B'}$ form the standard basis $\textbf{E}$ is given by $\textbf{B'}=\textbf{E}P$ and this changes the standard hermitian form$(X^* Y)$ to $X'^*PP^*Y'$ where $X',Y'$ are the new co ordinate vectors. (It was assumed that $P$ is invertible)

Fact 3:for an arbitrary linear transformation $T$ on an hermitian space $<T(v)\ ,\ w>\ =\ <v\ ,\ T^*(w)>$ for all $v,w$ that are in the hermitian space

Now, let the hermitian space be the space of $n$ dimensional complex column vectors.

Given $P$ an invertible matrix we change to a basis given by $\textbf{B'}=\textbf{E}P$.

Thus $<v\ ,\ w>\ =\ X^*PP^*Y$ where $X,Y$ is the co ordinate vector in the new basis.

Now given a complex matrix $A$, let left multiplication by $A$ to column vectors written in the new basis be the linear transformation $T$ on the hermitian space.

Now translation of Fact 3 into the co ordinate vector form we have:

$<T(v)\ ,\ w>\ =\ (AX)^*PP^*(Y)\ =\ (X^*)A^*PP^*(Y)$

$<v\ ,\ T^*(w)>\ =\ (X)^*PP^*(A^*Y)\ =\ (X^*)PP^*A^*(Y)$

but since both are equal by Fact 3,

$(X^*)A^*PP^*(Y)\ = \ (X^*)PP^*A^*(Y)$

Since this is true for arbitrary $X,Y$ it implies that:

$A^*PP^*\ =\ PP^*A^*$

Comment: Here it is to be assumed that the hermitian space is finite dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform your change of basis from the standard basis to the basis of $P$, as you note we have the relation $\vec{v}_s = P \vec{v}_p$, where $\vec{v}_s$ is in the standard basis and $\vec{v}_p$ is in the $P$ basis. It is also correct that given two vectors $\vec{v}_p$ and $\vec{w}_p$ in the $P$ basis, you can define the inner product is given by $\langle \vec{v}_p, \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = \vec{v}_p^* P^* P \vec{w}_p$. The problem is that the statement
$$\langle A\vec{v}_p, \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = \langle \vec{v}_p, A^*\vec{w}_p \rangle_P$$
is not actually true for all transformations $A$ for our inner product. The above property is only a property of the canonical inner product $ \langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle_S = \vec{v}^* \vec{w}$ and its multiples (i.e. $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle = k \vec{v}^* \vec{w}$, for some positive $k$). Here the inner product isn't one of them. Note that we can deduce a similar-looking property for this inner product, namely that
$$\langle A \vec{v}_p, \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = \langle \vec{v}_p, A_* \vec{w}_p\rangle$$
where $A_*$ is defined to be the matrix such that $A^* P^* P = P^* P A_*$. (This might seem trivial to you, but it's really the only property we can deduce without further information about $P$.)

On the other hand, what is true is that given two vectors $\vec{v}_s$ and $\vec{w}_s$ in the standard basis with the canonical inner product structure $\langle -, - \rangle_S$, we have for any linear transformation matrix $A$
$$\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle P \vec{v}_p, A^* P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S$$
But you will notice that this statement only trivially implies $P^* A^* P = P^* A^* P$.

**ADDENDUM:** Here are answers to your questions:

1. *What is meant by $\langle -, - \rangle_S$ and $\langle -, - \rangle_P$*? They are just two inner products:
   $$\langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle_S = \vec{v}^* \vec{w}, ~ \langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle_P = \vec{v}^* P^* P \vec{w}$$
   for some arbitrary fixed matrix $P$. While these formulas don't need a basis to make sense, when associating an inner product with a vector space, you have to specify a basis. What I mean to emphasize is the following. If $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are two vectors, with $\vec{v}_s$ and $\vec{w}_s$ as their representations in the standard basis, and $\vec{v}_p$ and $\vec{w}_p$ as their representations in the $P$ basis, the the canonical inner product $\langle -, - \rangle_S$ between $\vec{v}_p$ and $\vec{w}_p$ is equivalent to $\langle \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_P$. This is because $\vec{v}_s = P \vec{v}_p$, and similarly for $\vec{w}$.
2. *Should the line*
   $$\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle P \vec{v}_p, A^* P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S$$
   *instead read as*
   $$\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle P \vec{v}_p, A^* P \vec{w}_p \rangle_P ~?$$
   No, it should not; let's break it down. The first equality just uses the fact that $\vec{v}_s = P \vec{v}_p$, and likewise for $\vec{w}_s$. What you suggest would claim that
   $$\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = (\vec{v}_p^* P^* A^*) P^* P (P \vec{w}_p)$$
   which isn't true. Remember, the crucial reason the logic you presented fails is because
   $$\langle A \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle_P \neq \langle \vec{v}, A^* \vec{w} \rangle_P$$
   in general.

Comment: I seem to be slightly confused, $\langle  v, w \rangle = X^*Y = X'^*PP^*Y'$.Here $v$ and $w$ are just vectors without reference to any basis. What exactly does $\langle \vec{v}_p, \vec{w}_p \rangle_P $ and $\langle \vec{v}, \vec{w} \rangle_S $ mean?

Comment: And even in your terminology if $\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S$ this implies $(AX)^*Y=(A_PX')^*PP^*Y'=X^*(A^*Y)=X'^*PP^*(A_P^*Y')$. But since $A$ was arbitrary so is $A_P$

Comment: Or more specifically in your answer I believe the line: $\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle P \vec{v}_p, A^* P \vec{w}_p \rangle_S$ should instead be $\langle A \vec{v}_s, \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle A P \vec{v}_p, P \vec{w}_p \rangle_P = \langle \vec{v}_s, A^* \vec{w}_s \rangle_S = \langle P \vec{v}_p, A^* P \vec{w}_p \rangle_P$

Comment: @SnmohithRaju Please see my comments; if they do not clarify your confusion please ask more.

Answer (score 0):

The adjoint operator $T^*$, is defined as the adjoint of the matrix of the operator $T$, **wrt to an orthonormal basis**.

In other words: If $A$ is the matrix of $T$ wrt a basis which is **not** orthonormal, then $A^*$ **may not** be the matrix of $T^*$ wrt to this basis.

But I have assumed in my derivation[the above question] that if $A$ is the matrix of an operator with respect to an arbitrary basis then, $A^*$ is the matrix of the adjoint operator wrt to that arbitrary basis; Which is **Not necessarily true**.

Since the above is true if the basis is orthonormal, the above is true if the change of basis is from an orthonormal basis to another. This means $P$ should be unitary which implies $PP^*$ to be $I$, the identity matrix, and it is no surprise that the identity matrix commutes with all complex matrices of the same size.